# Avoid create session in Spring

Tags: java, spring, security, session, controller

I have a Spring web application that creates a session on each request, and I want to avoid this.

I have this configuration:

```
<security:http pattern="/**" auto-config='true' create-session="never" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And I call a controller

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/experiences", produces="application/json")
public String getExperiencesList(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value = "channel",required=true) String channel,
        @RequestParam(value = "page",required=true) int page,
        Model model) {  
    String path = "http://" + HOST + request.getContextPath();
    model.addAttribute("json", experienceService.getExperiencesList(page,channel,path));

    return "json";
}
```

This would be used through a mobile application and the same app could open infinite sessions, any idea how I can avoid this?.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid session creation? Yes having a unneeded session does cause some overhead but what problem does the session actually cause?

Comment: As per above configuration, Your App creates sessions and Spring Security will make use of it.

Comment: We are making a mobile app and this service is used to get a list of events, if each mobile creates a session would be a problem for the server.

Comment: Why would it be a problem for the server, the mobile app can use the cookie containing sessionid and use it for subsequent secured access. What are you thinking by making your app stateless is what I am wondering.

Comment: As it stands right now if you change the screen on the app and return to the same new sessions are created.
Those sessions are useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's done, I restructured the security and added some changes.

Added the security config in other file with this:

```
<http pattern="/**" security="none" create-session="never"/>
```

In web.xml:

```
<http create-session="never"></http>
```

And added session="false" on jsp page.

It seems to works fine now.